# How to select the duplicate rows / records in a large table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, duplicates

I have an Oracle table with 35 columns, one of which is a unique id.

This table has a few entries / rows that are duplicate.

When I do a `select distinct (*)` I get a number `x`

When I do a `select distinct ("every column but id")` I get a number `y < x`

Is there anyway I can get those columns that are duplicate, from this table?
A minus doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ("every column but id")
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
("every column but id")
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

To delete them

- insert the rows from above query into a temporary table
- delete all rows from above query including their duplicates from your table
- insert the rows from the temporary table into your table again

Comment: I can't accept an answer in 9 minutes it seems :|
Anyways, thanks a lot. Problem solved.

Comment: @fancyPants
Group by with count(*) on a large table (~40 million) will not be a good idea.

Comment: @Tayyab_Hussain You don't say. But sometimes one just has to bite the apple. When you're having problems with that, there are ways to lessen the pain. But this is certainly too much to discuss in the comments. Feel free to post a new question.

Comment: @fancyPants
already reported
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095438/get-duplicate-records-from-a-large-table?noredirect=1#comment81140720_47095438