# Get duplicate records from a large table

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I have a table on which I want to apply **unique constraint** on three columns,
Table have ~250000 records.
I want get duplicate records so that I can take a decision (what to do with duplicate data), My query takes more than 600 seconds and times out. I cannot increase the time for query.

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2, col3, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM
    table
WHERE
    col3 != ''
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING c > 1
```

I have tried using limit of 10 records but no luck.

EDIT :
Index has been added on all of these columns

Comment: Are any of those fields indexed? It also depends on the hardware it's on and if there is anything else competing for resources. Also, if it's a single use query, does 600 seconds matter that much? It's certainly annoying, but if you only run it once (and off hours etc) then I'd focus on other issues. That being said, if other queries are taking as long, then I'd look into the general performance of your server.

Comment: @kchason yes indexes have bee added on all of these columns, And If you are talking about off hours, I have observed the CPU utilization at amazon RDS instance,  It shoots up to 70% with this query, normal CPU usage 15% on average.

Comment: Please post the result of `show indexes from feedbacks;` and `explain <your_query>\G` and `show global variables like '%timeout%';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the faster way to fetch duplicate records from a large table,

```
SELECT n1.col1 , n1.col2 , n1.col3  
FROM table AS n1,
table AS n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.col1 = n2.col1 AND n1.col2 = n2.col2
AND n1.col3 = n2.col3;
```

This query will not return the count of duplicate records, but it will return duplicated records,